# How to combine table records with some condition in SQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have six tables in the database, all tables are relative to each other and want to show records in one table.

Following are my tables:

1) mls_stores

```
*----------------------------*
|   store_id |  store_title  |
*----------------------------*
|     1001   |  ajmar-jaipur |
|     1002   |  dwarka-delhi |
*----------------------------*
```

2) mls_category

```
*-------------------------------------------*
 | cat_no | store_id |  cat_value | cat_type |
 *-------------------------------------------*
 |  20    |   1001   |     1      | running  |
 |  21    |   1001   |     4      | cycling  |
 |  22    |   1002   |     1      | running  |
 |  23    |   1002   |     2      | swmining |
 *-------------------------------------------*
```

3) mls_points_matrix

```
*----------------------------------------*
| store_id | value_per_point |  maxpoint |
*----------------------------------------*
|   1001   |       1         |    10     |
|   1001   |       2         |    20     |
|   1002   |       1         |    20     |
|   1002   |       4         |    30     |
*----------------------------------------*
```

4) mls_user

```
*--------------------------*
| id |  store_id |  name   |
*--------------------------*
|  1 |  1001     | sandeep |
|  2 |  1001     | jagveer |
|  3 |  1002     | gagan   |
*--------------------------*
```

5) bonus_points

```
   *---------------------------------------------------*
   | user_id |  store_id |  bonus_points |  bonus_type |
   *---------------------------------------------------*
   |    1    |    1001   |     10        |   fixed     |
   |    3    |    1002   |      2        |     %       |
   *---------------------------------------------------*
```

6) mls_entry

```
*-------------------------------------------------------*
| user_id | store_id |  category |  distance |  status  |
*-------------------------------------------------------*
|   1     |   1001   |    20     |    10     | approved |
|   1     |   1001   |    21     |    40     | approved | 
|   1     |   1001   |    20     |     5     | reject   | 
|   2     |   1001   |    21     |    40     | approved | 
|   3     |   1002   |    22     |    10     | approved | 
|   3     |   1002   |    23     |    20     | approved |
*-------------------------------------------------------*
```

Now I want output as below:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| Name    |  Entries   | Points Earned | Bonus Points | Total Points | Total Amount |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| Sandeep | running(1) |       20      |      10      |     30       |     60       |
|         | cycling(1) |               |              |              |              |    
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| Jagveer | cycling(1) |       10      |      0       |     10       |     10       |    
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

I am using following code:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0)) AS points,
    ROUND(COALESCE(b.bonus_points, 0)) AS bonus_points,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0) + COALESCE(b.bonus_points, 0)) AS total_points
FROM mls_user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT e.user_id, e.status, SUM(e.distance / c.cat_value) AS points
    FROM mls_entry e
    INNER JOIN mls_category c
        ON e.store_id = c.store_id AND e.category = c.cat_no
    GROUP BY e.user_id
    HAVING e.status='approved'
) t1
    ON u.id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN bonus_points b
    ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE u.store_id = '1001'
ORDER BY
    total_points DESC
```

This SQL query giving me Point earned, bonus points and total points, But I am not able to find Entries And Total Amount and it is giving me wrong Point calculation for Sandeep, As per data one entry is rejected. so it should be 20, not 25.

My total amount will be for Sandeep 30X2(it is coming from point matrix) = 60
same like for jagveer, the total amount for jagveer 10X1 = 10.

I have created tables in  [DEMO](https://rextester.com/FWJBK98646)

Comment: Well phrased question +1. Do you have access to latest version of MySQL server (8.0) ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes.

Comment: `mls_points_matrix` has multiple entries for a `store_id` with no other FK. How to decide which points calculation logic to be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0)) AS points,
    ROUND(COALESCE(b.bonus_points, 0)) AS bonus_points,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0) + COALESCE(b.bonus_points, 0)) AS total_points,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0) + COALESCE(b.bonus_points, 0)) * t1.countId as total_amount,
    group_concat(t1.EntriesConcat) as Entries

FROM mls_user u
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT e.user_id, e.status, SUM(e.distance / c.cat_value) AS points,
    concat(c.cat_type, '(',count(e.user_id), ')' ) as EntriesConcat,
    count(e.user_id) as countId -- it returns count of records according to group by part
    FROM mls_entry e
        INNER JOIN mls_category c
            ON e.store_id = c.store_id AND e.category = c.cat_no
    -- remove HAVING and use WHERE clause
    WHERE e.status='approved'
    GROUP BY e.user_id
) t1 ON u.id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN bonus_points b ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE u.store_id = '1001'
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

- [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) of mysql is useful to concatinating values on `Group By`

Comment: Sorry for late revert, I have tried your script but it is giving me error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
    u.name,
    ROUND(COALESCE(t1.points, 0)) AS points,
    ROUND(COA' at line 23

Comment: If you want to check it in `rextester`, please put `;` at the end of last query.

Comment: Opps! my mistake. Sometimes i do silly mistake. by the way you are my hero.. you save my life. the output is perfect which i want but here i want count of entries as like Running(1), cycling(1) here  1 is showing that user has done one entry in running and one entry in cycle. So please last help me here to find this.